# How to Store the Response of a GET Request In a Local Variable In Node JS

Tags: node.js, get

I know the way to make a GET request to a URL using the `request` module. Eventually, the code just prints the GET response within the command shell from where it has been spawned.

How do I store these GET response in a local variable so that I can use it else where in the program?

This is the code i use:

```
var request = require("request");
request("http://www.stackoverflow.com", function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: Try to see this question before move: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: `body` is already a local variable within the function that's holding the response. You can copy the value to another variable declared before the request. But, because it's performed asynchronously, you won't have a guarantee that the request completed before attempting to use it beyond what's invoked inside of the `function (error, response, body)`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way (but it has pitfalls--see below) is to move `body` into the scope of the module.

```
var request = require("request");
var body;


request("http://www.stackoverflow.com", function(error, response, data) {
    body = data;
});
```

However, this may encourage errors. For example, you might be inclined to put `console.log(body)` right after the call to `request()`.

```
var request = require("request");
var body;


request("http://www.stackoverflow.com", function(error, response, data) {
    body = data;
});

console.log(body); // THIS WILL NOT WORK!
```

This will not work because `request()` is asynchronous, so it returns control before `body` is set in the callback.

You might be better served by creating `body` as an event emitter and subscribing to events.

```
var request = require("request");
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
var body = new EventEmitter();


request("http://www.stackoverflow.com", function(error, response, data) {
    body.data = data;
    body.emit('update');
});

body.on('update', function () {
    console.log(body.data); // HOORAY! THIS WORKS!
});
```

Another option is to [switch to using promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise).

Comment: Brother Trott,As Per Your Third Code The variable data will be holding GET response right?

Comment: `body` will contain the response in the first example, and `body.data` will contain the response in the last example.

Comment: bonus on the explanation on the control structure. This is a great answer.